# HTML CSS Website trying to fit my entire screen

Tags: html, css

So my website has all of what everyone says to add when it comes to the head area:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

However it doesn't work.
Instead, I'm getting this zoomed-in website that has the scroll bar on the right side(supposed to) AND one on the bottom (it isn't supposed to have a scroll bar on the bottom.)

Some perhaps useful info:
width:1920px
height: 3742px

IMAGE LINK:
https://ibb.co/W53qHnq

Code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FpUiJsbVPp5Q33sa91lMJ9QYMU1cf8jHwkmlnzP33Y8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to add html/css. And most likely if you are using <img> tag, it needs width or it might take the width of the image used.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the problem is your background image is too big, exceeding the viewport. You need to style the image to fit in the viewport. Exact code depends on your current image code, please provide.

Also, set `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper/container of the image to hide both scrollbars or `overflow-x: hidden` to hide just the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Yeah however, when I do that, it simply just hides those bars without changing anything. My code is based of images.
Link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FpUiJsbVPp5Q33sa91lMJ9QYMU1cf8jHwkmlnzP33Y8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @UniversalDuggal Wow.. that's 90 pages of code!

I guess it is this line:

`<img id="wesbite_bg" src="wesbite_bg.png" srcset="wesbite_bg.png 1x, wesbite_bg@2x.png 2x">`

In this case, try changing the width and overflow like this:

`#wesbite_bg {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}`

You may also need to consider the `object-fit` property.

Comment: That doesn't work. The section which you are talking about isnt associated with the CSS aspect but the HTML aspect. In any case, that isn't working

Comment: Would you please narrow down your problem with minimal code, both HTML and CSS?